# Is 1 Hz equal to 1 rotation of a motor shaft?

Tags: motor, dc, frequency, rpm

I'm rather new to the world of electronics but I have been trying to find the frequency of a DC motor. I've found that 1 hz is equal to 1 revolution per second, but does that refer to shaft rotation or something else because it seems almost too easy if thats the case. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: 1 rotation of a motor shaft (your title) could take days, hours, minutes or seconds and is therefore unrelated to frequency.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, no. 1Hz is defined as 1s<sup>-1</sup>.

While one rotation of the motor shaft could be considered one cycle, it would be better to use a unit of angular velocity, such as rad/s, DPS, or RPM.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean 1Hz *electrical* frequency, then it depends on the construction of the motor.

In a motor with 2 magnet poles, each armature winding (brushed motor) or stator phase (3 phase BLDC motor) gets one cycle per revolution, so if the motor is doing one revolution per second the electrical frequency is 1Hz. However a 4 pole motor only does half a revolution per electrical cycle, a 6 pole motor does 1/3 revolution etc. To get the motor's rotational velocity (rpm, rad/s etc.) by measuring the electrical frequency you need to take into account the number of magnet poles.

Note that *brushed* motor 'poles' are often the number of armature arms rather than magnet poles, so a '3 pole' and a '5 pole' brushed motor are both 2 pole motors electrically if they have 2 magnets. The only thing that matters is how many alternating North and South *magnet* poles go past each armature (or stator) arm per revolution.

Electrical frequency is also a factor in the design of a brushless controller, as it has to commutate at the electrical frequency, not the mechanical speed. For example a brushless controller with maximum commutation frequency of 1kHz could run a 2 pole motor up to 60,000rpm, but can only run a 36 pole motor up to 3,333rpm.

Comment: Alright, I dont have access to the motor at the moment but when I do I need to try and figure out the frequency so I can get the proper PWM controller for it, thanks guys!

Comment: Motor rpm has little to do with 'proper' PWM frequency, which is determined by motor inductance, audible noise and vibration, and switching losses. Iron cored motors have high inductance so they can work efficiently with PWM frequencies as low as 2~3kHz. Coreless motors need 20~30kHz. A frequency of >=20kHz may also be used to reduce audible noise. However higher frequencies increase switching losses, so >30kHz is rarely used.